# Python string-based if-statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I am writing a Python script for a project I am working on, and I am running into an error that I can't figure out. I am fairly new to Python, so I apologize if this is a very amateur question.

I have an if statement that is comparing a string that it got from a text file. it is supposed to take this input, then return a string with a file location depending on what the input was. However, when I run the script, it always resolves to the else clause, even when the input is exactly what it is being compared against.

```
def findfile(input):
     if input.lower() == 'option a':
          return 'file location a'
     elif input.lower() == 'option b':
          return 'file location b'
     elif input.lower() == 'option c':
          return 'file location c'
     elif input.lower() == 'option d':
          return 'file location d'
     else:
          return 'Invalid Input'
```

I have checks earlier in the script so that I know that the input being passed is a string. Regardless, even if I passed a string `'option b'`, it would return `'Invalid Input'`.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: There is a built-in function `input()` in Python. Do not use this name for your parameters or variables. Also, consider a dictionary lookup in `{'option a' : 'file location a', ...}` instead of the cascaded `if`.

Comment: Side-note: Save a little work, and perform the case conversion once, just put `input = input.strip().lower()` as the first line of the function, and remove the `.lower()` calls from each conditional test. And don't give variables the same name as Python built-ins (e.g. `input`) or you'll mess yourself up eventually. Perhaps `inp` or `inputstr`.

Comment: `findfile('option b')` returns `'file location b'` so I'm guessing it isn't actually that string.

Comment: **print** is a cheap, but effective debugging tool.  As the first statement of your function, put **print "|" + input + "|", len(input)**.  This will give you a solid idea of what you actually fed to the function.

Answer (score 2):

This might happen if you get input from a file, because the string has a trailing newline. Use `strip` to remove it.

Comment: @JohnGredler Debugging with `print`, as suggested by Prune, would have shown the problem.  This seems to be neglected in courses, but is extremely valuable to learn.